# use Google Map API to save location info

Tags: google-places-api

I am using Google Places API to get user location info. Based on the T&C (https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms), I cannot cache the lag & long info for more than 30 days. In my use case, I will ask the user to confirm the location based on location detection provided by Google Places API. If we would like to save the location level info (such as city and town) of users, what's the best way? thanks.

Currently, I can only cache the placeid for 30 days.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that it is only the LatLngs that have a 30 days limit of storage. For the Place ID, you can store it as long as you are able to. So saving a placeID should work fine instead of the addresses. see: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms#:~:text=3.4%20Caching.%20Customer,API%20Policies.

Comment: Thanks Yrll for your reply. For us, we would like to have the location info, such as zipcode, state, city, county, etc. Having Place ID doesn't help much.

Comment: You can just store the Place ID and then use it to show/use the data in your interface/implementation whenever needed. There's no way as of now to store the data itself as I believe that it would be against the Terms as mentioned above.

Comment: understand. thank you!